# I don't know how the default arguments of the function works inside the python

Tags: python, function, default

Here there's two simple codes I don't understand.

```
def buggy(arg,result=[]):   
  result.append(arg)
  print(result)
  print('---')

buggy('a')
buggy('b')
buggy('c')
buggy('d')
```

output:

### ['a']

### ['a', 'b']

### ['a', 'b', 'c']

### ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

```
def buggy(arg,result=[]):
   if len(result)==0:
       result=[]

   result.append(arg)
   print(result)
   print('---')

buggy('a')
buggy('b')
buggy('c')
buggy('d')
```

output:

### ['a']

### ['b']

### ['c']

### ['d']

I think if first code's output is True, the second code's output must to be the same as the first code's output. what happened?

Comment: Here it's explained. https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#what-you-wrote

Comment: This explanation is not enough. What exactly I wonder is.... if python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, in the second code, list 'result' is ['a'] right before buggy('b') is implemented. so len(result) is not 0 and result is still ['a'] after  'if' statement is implemented. so the output of buggy('b') should be ['a','b'] but it is not! could you please explain about this mismatch.

Comment: instead of printing `result` print yourself `id(result)` before and after `result=[]`. You create a new pointer in your if statement. If you run `result.clear()` instead of new assignment `result=[]` you will get your expected behavior. Imo a good question :)